# Importance of uniform stationary distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, sampling

When I study Markov chain (or sampling) related papers, most of them emphasize "uniform stationary distribution". But, I can't sure why it is important for Markov chain problems or randomized algorithms. Is this because uniform stationary distribution easily satisfies the reversibility of our Markov chain?

If possible, could you please give me some references or explanations? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually uniform stationary distributions are not *more important* than other stationary distributions and one often designs Markov chains with the exact goal to simulate non uniform distributions.

Comment: @Did could you please explain the advantage when we make a Markov chain with an uniform stationary distribution? Thanks!

Comment: Funny, I just explained there was no advantage... Did you actually read my first comment?

Comment: @Did I thought "not more important" did not mean "no advantage". Anyway, thanks for your comment.